# Bar chart using d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've got my d3 code and it's displaying no errors in the console but it's also not showing my bar chart. I'm a bit lost as to where I'm going wrong since I'm not getting any errors and it is reading in my data. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
async function drawBars() {
//setting the margin of svg
const margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};

//set the width and heigh using the current width and height of the div
const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//create svg and append to visualisation div
const svg = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//set the ranges for the scales
const x = d3.scaleBand()
.range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([height, 0]);

const data = await d3.csv("./../remote_work.csv")
console.log(data);

//scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
return d.Benefits; 
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
return d.Percentage;
})]);

svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.Benefits);
})
.attr("width", x.bandwidth())
.attr("y", function(d) { 
    return y(d.Percentage);
})
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.Percentage);
});

//add the axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

}
drawBars()
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `d.Percentage` to a number using either `Number(d.Percentage)` or `+d.Percentage`.

This is because the CSV file reader doesn't know whether any part of it is a number, whether it is a string that just happens to be made up completely of numbers, or whether this is the only value that is also a number, and the same column in another row is actually a string.

That is why it doesn't take any chances and just treats everything as a string. This means that it's up to you to make sure the data is of the right type.

I'd do this by changing your code to something like this:

```
const data = (await d3.csv(...).then(
  rows => rows.map(d => ({
    Benefits: d.Benefits,
    Percentage: Number(d.Percentage)
  })));
```

---

My working snippet with generated data:

```js
const data = ["Lease car", "401(k)", "Flexible hours"]
  .map(v => ({
    Benefits: v,
    Percentage: Math.random().toString()
  }))
  .map(d => ({
    Benefits: d.Benefits,
    Percentage: Number(d.Percentage)
  }));

function drawBars() {
  //setting the margin of svg
  const margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  };

  //set the width and heigh using the current width and height of the div
  const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  //create svg and append to visualisation div
  const svg = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  //set the ranges for the scales
  const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width]);

  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  //scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Benefits;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.Percentage;
  })]);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.Benefits);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.Percentage);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.Percentage);
    });

  //add the axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

}
drawBars()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualisation"></div>
```

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223821/discussion-about-bar-chart-using-d3)